# Change the Default Value of Is_active for customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I am using Magento 2.1.0, and when any customer register , by default is_active value is 1. even there is no way to change it manually from admin panel.

```
 )->addColumn(
        'is_active',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        ['unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'default' => '1'],
        'Is Active'
```

This the is the quary is used in default customer module.

My question is , how will i enable in admin panel in customer form and in customer grid for manual change, and put the default value is 0.

Comment: why did you reject my edit?

Comment: tell me one thing teja, from every post you are removing tag magento-2.1. why???

Comment: even i want to know from @rakesh jesadiya, how this question is related to customer-account? this question is related to customer module for the admin panel, and there will be putting some function like status.

Comment: @sam, customer-register is related to customer account.

Comment: ok .... thanx rakesh

Comment: @sam, magento-2 and magento-2.1 both are tags i am agree with you. but, both are belongs to one version only.

check  https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/usage-of-the-magento-1-tag-if-no-version-is-specified-in-question/782#782

Comment: @teja, no version 2.0 and version 2.1 is same version. like magento 1 and magento 1.9 is not the same thing. i think both tag will be halpful for anyone to find this question.